# Redmine Java API: get Issues based on customField value

Tags: java, redmine-api

I am trying to fetch issues based on customField Value.
Tried following but no luck so far. Please help.

```
Params params = new Params();
```

*/* Getting params from map*/*

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : paramMap.entrySet()) {  
          params.add(mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());  
}
    ResultsWrapper<Issue> sqLst;
```

//1. Didn't work

```
CustomField customField = CustomFieldFactory.create(cfIdBusinessOwner, "Business Owner", "");  
        customField.setValue("ABC");  
        params.add("custom_fields", customField);
```

//2. Didn't work

```
 params.add("custom_field[" + cfIdBusinessOwner + "]", "abc");
```

//3. Didn't work

```
 params.add("cf[" + cfIdBusinessOwner + "]", "abc");
```

//Continuous Code

```
params.add("status_id", "*");  
    issueLst= issueManager.getIssues(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time on the internet finally, I could figure out how to. and it is really simple and straightforward.

```
params.add("cf_X", "Value");
```

where **X** is the id of CustomField and **Value** is what you want to look for.

I am still trying to figure out how to look for ***part of the value for given field*** like we do in SQL like operator **'%XYZ%'**.

Please help me if someone already has some clue on that.

**UPDATE**

Found the answer to my second query in the answer above about search with like operator:
**Solution:**

```
paramMap.put("set_filter","1");`
paramMap.put("f[]","cf_X");
paramMap.put("op[cf_X]","~");
paramMap.put("v[cf_X][]","PartOfValue");
```

Where **X** is the custom field ID and **PartOfValue** is what you want to search is given field

Answer (score 0):

```
params.add("cf_X", "Value");
```

where **X** is the id of a **CustomField** and **Value** is what you want to look for.

Work for me. Also, remember that a Custom field must have 'used as a filter' checked.

Answer (score 0):

While the answers are correct here.
This option will work only when the project_id is used along side the cf_X filter

For Eg:
http://redmine.com/issues.xml?project_id=projectName&cf_77=Transition

Else this will continue to return all the issues without filtering